# Compare columns in different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one with daily info starting in 1990 and one with daily info starting in 2000. Both dataframes contain information ending in 2016.

```
df1:

   Date       A     B     C 
1990-01-01   3.0  40.0  70.0  
1990-01-02  20.0  50.0  80.0  
1990-01-03  30.0  60.0  90.0  
1990-01-04   2.0   1.0   1.0 
1990-01-05   1.0   8.0   3.0  

df2:

   Date       A     B     C 
2000-01-01   NaN   NaN   NaN  
2000-01-02   5.0   NaN   NaN  
2000-01-03   1.0   NaN   5.0  
2000-01-04   2.0   4.0   8.0 
2000-01-05   1.0   3.0   4.0
```

I need to compare columns in df1 and df2 which have the same name, which wouldn't usually be too complicated, but I need to compare them from the point at which there is data available in **both** dataframes for a given column (e.g from `df2`, `2000-01-02` in column `'A'`, `2000-01-04` in `'B'`). I need to return `True` if they are the same from that point on and `False` if they are different. I have started by merging, which gives me:

```
df2.merge(df1, how = 'left', on = 'Date')


   Date      A.x   B.x   C.x   A.y   B.y   C.y   
2000-01-01   NaN   NaN   NaN   3.0   4.0   5.0
2000-01-02   5.0   NaN   NaN   5.0   9.0   2.0
2000-01-03   1.0   NaN   5.0   1.0   6.0   5.0
2000-01-04   2.0   4.0   8.0   2.0   4.0   1.0
2000-01-05   1.0   3.0   4.0   1.0   3.0   3.0
```

I have figured out how to find the common date, but am stuck as to how to do the same/different comparison. Can anyone help me compare the columns from the point at which there is a common value? A dictionary comes to mind as a useful output format, but wouldn't be essential:

```
comparison_dict = {
    "A" : True,
    "B" : True,
    "C" : False
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't get that output at all when I merge on `Date`.  Also, it seems that none of the column values in `df1` and `df2` are equal anywhere.  It looks like you copied the wrong `df1`

Comment: apologies, yes, wrong data was copied

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `Date` column is the index.

1. Stacking will drop nan by default
2. Align with `'inner'` logic
3. Check equality
4. Group and check all `True`

---

```
pd.Series.eq(*df1.stack().align(df2.stack(), 'inner')).groupby(level=1).all()
```

If `Date` is not the index

```
pd.Series.eq(
    *df1.set_index('Date').stack().align(
        df2.set_index('Date').stack(), 'inner'
    )
).groupby(level=1).all()
```

Answer (score 6):

Check with `eq` and `isnull` Data from `user3483203`

```
((df1.eq(df2))|df2.isnull()|df1.isnull()).all(0)
Out[22]: 
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Very nice, it looks like the check for `isnull` is faster than using `fillna`

Comment: what if `df1` has the nulls?  You'd want `((df1.eq(df2) | df2.isna() | df1.isna()).all(0)`

Answer (score 4):

#### Using `fillna` with `eq`

```
df2.fillna(df1).eq(df1).all(0)
```

```
A        True
B        True
C       False
dtype: bool
```

---

This works by filling in `NaN` values with valid values from `df1`, so they will always be equal where `df2` is null (essentially the same as  ignoring them).  Next, we create a boolean mask comparing the two arrays:

```
df2.fillna(df1).eq(df1)
```

```
               A     B      C
2000-01-01  True  True   True
2000-01-02  True  True   True
2000-01-03  True  True   True
2000-01-04  True  True  False
2000-01-05  True  True  False
```

Finally, we assert that all the values for each column are `True`, in order for the columns to be considered equal.

---

***Setup***

It looks like you copied the wrong DataFrame for `df1` based on your desired output and merge, so I derived it from your `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2000-01-01': 3.0, '2000-01-02': 5.0, '2000-01-03': 1.0, '2000-01-04': 2.0, '2000-01-05': 1.0}, 'B': {'2000-01-01': 4.0, '2000-01-02': 9.0, '2000-01-03': 6.0, '2000-01-04': 4.0, '2000-01-05': 3.0}, 'C': {'2000-01-01': 5.0, '2000-01-02': 2.0, '2000-01-03': 5.0, '2000-01-04': 1.0, '2000-01-05': 3.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2000-01-01': np.nan, '2000-01-02': 5.0, '2000-01-03': 1.0, '2000-01-04': 2.0, '2000-01-05': 1.0}, 'B': {'2000-01-01': np.nan, '2000-01-02': np.nan, '2000-01-03': np.nan, '2000-01-04': 4.0, '2000-01-05': 3.0}, 'C': {'2000-01-01': np.nan, '2000-01-02': np.nan, '2000-01-03': 5.0, '2000-01-04': 8.0, '2000-01-05': 4.0}})
```